# Multiple ports in docker for docker_sd scraping for Prometheus

Tags: docker, prometheus, service-discovery

I found a problem with my use of `docker_sd` for containers with multiple exposed ports. If a container is exposing more than one port, and has metrics only on one port, `docker_sd` is 'discovering' each such port as a target. Only one of them has metrics, and others are 'down', because they can't answer to `/metrics`.

I wonder if there is a way to use `relabel_config` to drop some ports from scrapping. But I can't find a way to compare one label to another (I thought I can drop targets with

```
__meta_docker_port_public != __meta_docker_container_label_scrape_port
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I could solve it, because all my containers use the same port for metrics. I could drop all other ports with [`relabel_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config):

> `<relabel_action>` determines the relabeling action to take:
>
> - `replace`: Match `regex` against the concatenated `source_labels`. Then, set `target_label` to `replacement`, with match group references (`${1}`, `${2}`, ...) in `replacement` substituted by their value. If `regex` does not match, no replacement takes place.
> - `lowercase`: Maps the concatenated `source_labels` to their lower case.
> - `uppercase`: Maps the concatenated `source_labels` to their upper case.
> - `keep`: Drop targets for which `regex` does not match the concatenated `source_labels`.
> - `drop`: Drop targets for which `regex` matches the concatenated `source_labels`.

**My configuration**

```yaml
scrape_configs:

  - job_name: docker
    metrics_path: '/prometheus'
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_docker_port_private]
        regex: '8081'
        action: keep
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
        regex: '/(.*)'
        target_label: 'job'
      - source_labels: [__meta_docker_container_log_stream]
        target_label: source
```